# Использование Expression Language в JSP

Tags: jsp, java

Подскажите, для чего целесообразно использовать Expression Language при создании JSP? Если есть примеры, это тоже было бы полезно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте EL всегда, когда надо подставить нестатическое значение. Используйте EL всегда, когда возможно обойтись без Java-вставок. А лучше, никогда не использовать Java-вставок. Например, я никогда не использую Java-вставки и на практике всегда удаётся обойтись без них.

Например, так:

```
<a href="show.jsp?id=${myObject.id}">${myObject.title}</a>
```

Или в связке с Custom Tags, например, с JSTL:

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach values="${pageBean.myItems}" var="item">
        <li>${item.title}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Или вот, например, для раскраски строк таблицы

```
<c:forEach values="${myTable.rows}" var="row">
    <tr class="${my:rowClass(row)}">..... </tr>
</c:forEach>
```